# Slow text printing in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way in Python3 to slow the text that is inside a function?
I have created a text-based game that uses almost exclusively functions for each section of the game, but want the text within to be typed out.
For example:

```py
def room_1():
    Print("You are in a foyer.")
    Print("You can see a painting on the wall.")
```

etc.

I have already imported, sys,time and is.
I have tried putting this inside the function but it doesn't seem to work:

```py
for char in room_1():
    Sys.stdout.write(char)
    Sys.stdout.flush()
    Time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: `room_1` *prints output*; it does not return a string you can iterate over.

Comment: `Sys` is different from `sys`. `Print` is different from `print`. `Time` is different from `time`. Names are case sensitive.

Comment: Yes, in the program itself I do not have them capitalized, it was just a typo in this question itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close, but you should look up some tutorials on how iterators work with Python. `print` doesn't return a value and your `room_1` definition also doesn't return anything so your code was not entering the `for` loop.

I would recommend making a function that will print slowly.

```
import sys
import time

def slow_print(input_str):
    for c in input_str:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write('\n')

def room_1():
    slow_print("You are in a foyer.")
    slow_print("You can see a painting on the wall.")

room_1()
```

Comment: @Kellenwood Glad I could help. Feel free to click the green checkmark to accept the answer for anyone else that stumbles on this question.